# iOS Cell Label link

Tags: objective-c, ios

Hi I am new to iOS programming and I need a little help.

I have a table view cell which is populated by data from a .plist file. I need to be able to make a link within one of the cells. How could I do this?

Here is the code which is loading the data into the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";
    static NSString *CellNib = @"DetailViewCell";



    DetailViewCell *cell = (DetailViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellNib owner:self options:nil];
        cell = (DetailViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }   

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.cellTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.cellTitleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0];
    cell.cellSubtitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    informations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"City", @"Country", @"State", @"History", @"Link", nil];
    subtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleString, subtitleString, stateString, populationString, @"Link", nil];


    cell.cellTitleLabel.text = [informations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.cellSubtitleLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return (DetailViewCell *) cell; 
}
```

For the cell "Link" I need it to open a url which is stored in the .plist file. How could i do this?

Many thanks

Ryan

PS: I'm a newbie at this stuff, so be descriptive. Thanks

Comment: This is one of the idea I can suggest. Create a new view consists of UIWebView & In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of above class, u can condition check for `indexpath` of that 'Link' cell. And open the url from that cell in the newly created UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firs of all, move the following to viewDidLoad

```
   informations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"City", @"Country", @"State", @"History", @"Link", nil];
    subtitles = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleString, subtitleString, stateString, populationString, @"Link", nil];
```

Second, for the cell that has a value of @"Link"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    DetailViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell.cellTitleLabel.text == @"Link")
    {
          //Open in safari
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:cell.cellSubtitleLabel.text]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, with a little adjustment, I managed to get this working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm stuck on something else now, regarding UIActionsheets with iPad. See my profile for question. Not to worry if you cannot help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make the two arrays properties of your viewController.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *informationArray, *subtitlesArray;
```

Initialise them in your `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
   self.informationArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"City", @"Country", @"State", @"History", @"Link", nil];
   self.subtitlesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:titleString, subtitleString, stateString, populationString, @"Link", nil];
```

and then check to see if the retrieved data is a link, then open it in safari.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    id title = [self.informationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.subtitlesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    //or to get the link out of a .plist

    NSDictionary *plist = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePathForPlist];

    NSURL *link = [NSURL URLWithString:[[plist objectForKey:title] objectForKey:@"Link"];

    // you may need to get a different object from the .plist depending on the structure of the file.

    //Check to see if the indexPath matches a cell with a title of "Link" and that the URL can be opened.

    if([title isEqualToString:@"Link"] && [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:link]) {

          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:link];

    }
}
```